# Get Error creating windows handles in a function

Tags: vb.net

Public Function GetMetaDataFromPIC(ByVal _imgpath As String) As String
Dim fname As String
Dim RichTextBox1 As New RichTextBox
Dim myStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
Dim OneLine As String
Dim ffmpeg As Process
Dim Fi As FileInfo

```
    Try
        Application.DoEvents()
        Fi = New FileInfo(_imgpath)
        'fcreated_date = Fi.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString
        fname = _imgpath
        ffmpeg = New Process
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = """" & Application.StartupPath & "\exiftool.exe"""
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        'ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "-verbose  & """ & _imgpath & """  "
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "  & """ & _imgpath & """  "
        ffmpeg.Start()
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""
        myStreamReader = ffmpeg.StandardOutput
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        OneLine = myStreamReader.ReadLine()
        Do
            '  Application.DoEvents()
            i = i + 1
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(OneLine + System.Environment.NewLine)
            OneLine = myStreamReader.ReadLine()
            If i > 200 Then Exit Do
        Loop Until ffmpeg.HasExited And (OneLine Is Nothing)
        If RichTextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            GetMetaDataFromPIC = RichTextBox1.Text
        Else
            GetMetaDataFromPIC = ""
        End If
        myStreamReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Write_ErrorLog(ex.Message & vbTab & "GetMetaDataFromPIC of " & _imgpath)
        GetMetaDataFromPIC = ""
    Finally

    End Try

End Function
```

this is the code i am using to find metadata of image but everyday once in night i get this Error Creating Windows Handles error and it crash my application.

Comment: So much going on here.  Why even use a richtextbox when all your doing is returning a string?  Where exactly is this exception happening, can you update your log to include the stack trace maybe(ex.ToString())?  Always worried when seeing Application.DoEvents(), why? Don’t seem to be disposing stream objects. Far better methods to construct paths.

Comment: RichTextBox1.Dispose() is missing.  Required to prevent runaway handle usage.